# Rake dependencies with multitask

Tags: ruby, rake

How do Rake dependencies work with multitask?

Things aren't working as I expect, and I decided to test my usage of multitask using a small test case here.

Here are some tasks I have defined:

- multitask A => [B, C]
- multitask B
- multitask C => [B]

When I run "rake A", the following happens, sequentially:

1. B runs
2. B runs again
3. C runs

How do I make it so the following happens when I run "rake A"?

1. B runs
2. C runs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created a quick Rakefile to try and see what you are seeing. Here is the code:

```
multitask :a => [:b, :c] do |t|
  puts "a"
end

multitask :b do |t|
  puts "b"
end

multitask :c => [:b] do |t|
  puts "c"
end
```

The result is the following:

```
$ rake a
b
c
a
```

It seems to do what you expect. I am using rake-10.3.2 with Ruby 2.1.2.

Comment: Well I have task B depend on C, so I used what you had and added B to the dependency of C and task B runs twice.

Comment: @ShuoFeng I've updated my answer to match your original question. Sorry I missed that. I'm still seeing the same output though. I also tried with :c depending on :b and I get `c b a`. If you copy this into a `Rakefile` and run `rake a` do you see the same results?

Comment: I was using rake 10.0.3, and after updating to 10.3.2, I got the same result you got. Thanks!